# Relation between polynomial convexity and Runge-Stein neighborhood basis

Tags: several-complex-variables

I am searching for some reference about the relation between polynomial convexity and Runge-Stein neighborhood basis for a compact set $K$ inside $\Bbb C^n$.

I read on [this paper, Remark 3.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6759.pdf), that having a Runge-Stein neighbourhood basis implies poynomial convexity. Where can I find a proof? What about the other implication?
Thanks